# Why is conditional operator giving desired result for first statement but not for second?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Second one is giving some sky blue color

```
#define GREEN_COLOR           0x69BC63
#define RED_COLOR             0xCC4C46
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

//Working
[amount setTextColor: [[trans amount] intValue]>=0 ? UIColorFromRGB(GREEN_COLOR):UIColorFromRGB(RED_COLOR)];

//Not working
[amount setTextColor: UIColorFromRGB([[trans amount] intValue]>=0 ? GREEN_COLOR:RED_COLOR)];
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh The question is about `C`, indeed.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy hmm... then I'm seriously missing something... i don't think these statements will compile...

Comment: @SouravGhosh The question is about `why the C if-else short-hand` not working here. The question is not related to `Objective C` at all I think, but not sure.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy you're confusing me, sir...

Comment: @SouravGhosh :) yes, wrote `C` instead of `Objective C` here.

Comment: @Parul how can this `if` give you different results which you named `sky blue color`? It should give you exactly one of two objects you return from the if-else shorthand. Where is `sky blue color` here?

Comment: Add the definition of `UIColorFromRGB`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas .. I added defination

Comment: @VictorPolevoywhy don't you try it on ur xcode, Sky blue color is coming randomly.. I haven't used it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parentheses problem.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

can be redone as

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)(((rgbValue) & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)(((rgbValue) & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)((rgbValue) & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

which should fix your issue, but makes the macro even harder to read.

---

You really should consider making this a proper function instead of a macro.

At the very least use a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) so `rgbValue` is evaluated only once.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) ({ unsigned v = rgbValue; [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((v & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((v & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(v & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]; })
```

Comment: Indeed; `&` has a higher precedence than `?:`.